# Finite presentability of a group

Tags: group-theory

Le $F$ be a free group of infinite rank (say countable rank) and consider a semidirect product $G = F \rtimes \mathbb Z$. Is it possible that $G$ is finitely presentable? If not, can we say something about the structure of the finitely presentable subgroups of $G$?

Note that $G$ can be finitely generated. For example, if we let $F$ be freely generated by $x_i$ for $i \in \mathbb Z$ and let the stable letter $t$ act via $t x_i t^{-1} = x_{i+1}$, then $G$ is generated by $x_0$ and $t$.

I have a related question which is as follows: If $G$ is an arbitrary group with finite presentation $\langle S \mid Q \rangle$ and if $\langle T \mid R \rangle$ is another presentation for $G$ with $T$ and/or $R$ infinite, can we obtain a finite presentation for $G$ by removing elements from $T$ respectively $R$? I know that we have a positive answer if we assume that $T$ is finite.

Comment: As a complement to Derek's answer: this is quite ubiquitous. For instance, if $G$ is a surface group (of some closed surface of genus $\ge 2$), then for every homomorphism from $G$ onto $\mathbf{Z}$ (there are many such homomorphisms since the abelianization of $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^{2g}$), the kernel is free of infinite rank, and a choice of a basis along with an element mapping to $1\in\mathbf{Z}$ yields a semidirect decomposition $G=F_\infty\rtimes\mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, it is possible for $G$ to be finitely presentable. The free group $F$ on two generators $a,b$ is the semidirect product of the normal closure of $a$ in $F$ with the infinite cyclic subgroup generated by $b$. (This is the same example that you gave. In your example, $F$ is freely generated by $t$ and $x_0$.)

The answer to the second question is yes and yes. Express the generators  $S$ as words in $T^{\pm 1}$, and these words can only involve finitely many elements of $T$, and they generate $G$. Similarly, rewrite the relators $Q$ over the (now finite) set of generators $T$, and express these as products of conjugates of elements of $R^{\pm 1}$. Again you only need finitely many elements of $R$ and they form a set of defining relators. (I glossed over a technicality in that last part.)